# LogicApp liquid transform using ceil operator

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I have a Liquid transform JSON-JSON. I have the following:

```
{
    "Ceiling":{{  44.25 | Ceil }},
}
```

But i'm getting

```
 "Ceiling":  44.25
```

and not

```
"Ceiling": 45
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems that Ceil is not working with Liquid Maps, if you use with the same syntax a similar operator as "Round", it works "Ceiling": {{  44.25 | Round }}.

Comment: But round will round down 44.25 to 44. I need to round it up to 45 when the number is higher that the whole number.

Comment: I know, I only was saying that the syntax seems correct, but Ceil operator it's not working. I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Plus, Minus, DividedBy, Modulo, Round, ... works fine, but Ceil, Floor and Abs are not working, maybe is a bug :-(

Answer (score -1):

As felixmondelo said, you could use [Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-round) to round a number.

> The Round, RoundDown, and RoundUp functions round a number to the specified number of decimal places:
>   ·**Round** rounds up if the next digit is a 5 or higher. Otherwise, this function rounds down.
>   ·**RoundDown** always rounds down to the previous lower number.
>   ·**RoundUp** always rounds up to the next higher number.

I test in logic app and reproduce your problem, it maybe some bug. You could use the following code to test:

```
{"Ceiling":"{{  44.75 | Round }}"}
```

Comment: I want to round 44.25 to 45. RoundUp filter does not exist in dotliquid

Comment: It seems that `Ceil` is not working with Liquid Maps. You could give a feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to promote the function achievement. Also, if you still want to the number to roundup filter, you could use azure function to achieve it.